# Update multiple columns in MySQL if unique ID exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a relatively small database table with six columns.

`ID | Rank | PrevRank | Player | Country | Points |`

ID is obviously the unique key. I want to be able to update all columns in a record ONLY if the UNIQUE key is not the same.

```
INSERT INTO rankings (id,rank,prevrank,player,country,points)
VALUES ($id, $rank, $prevrank, $player, $country, $points)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..... ;
```

I am not sure what comes after the ellipses. I have seen the below as an exampe but that only deals with updating one column.

`` INSERT INTO funds (`fund_id`, `date`, `price`) VALUES (23, DATE('2013-02-12'), 22.5) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price` = `price`; ``

I am hoping you can do a comma-separated list but I don't want to ruin my database finding out!

Comment: But.. Unique keys will never be the same I guess? Aren't you doing auto increment on your ID column?

Comment: Do a database backup, restore it in a different database and play around. But you are corect, you can do comma separated list of your instructions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `ON DUPLICATE KEY` has the behavior of _updating_ a record if the record already matches the unique key, not the other way around.  If the record isn't duplicate, an update would not happen.

Comment: It will do an INSERT unless the KEY already exists. I'm sure there is a bit of an English issue here as you can only update a thing that already exists

Comment: Er, that's what the backup is for. You have a backup, right?

Comment: Also, before you go too far down this road, take a look at parametrised queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normal update structure after `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, example:

```
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rank=$rank, player=$player, etc ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Also took a back up before starting this but it worked perfectly. Good advice for all involved.